# Deleting child object from parent when something happens in child's internal thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, memory-management

Let's say I have `ObjectA` (of `classA`), which contains:

```
List<classB> bList;
```

now let's suppose that in each `objectB` there are a couple of threads which are running (they can't be accessed from outside `objectB`), `threadB1` and `threadB2`.

Now, in a certain `objectB` of such list, `threadB2` discovers that `objectBRemove==true`.

When that happens, I want to terminate all threads from such object and remove it from `bList` (I effectively want to destroy this `objectB`).

I thought I could rise an event inside `objectB` and subscribe a `objectA`'s method to such event:

```
public void onObjectBRemove(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bList.Remove((classB) sender);
}
```

When this is called after `objectB`'s event rising this should remove `objectB` from the list. Then, the garbage collector should notice `objectB` becoming unreferenced and thus deleting it, also terminating all internal threads.

Is this supposed to work? Is this a reasonable approach to the problem at hand?

Answer (score 3):

> When this is called after objectB's event rising this should remove objectB from the list. Then, the garbage collector should notice objectB becoming unreferenced and thus deleting it, also terminating all internal threads.

This will remove the object from the list - but `List<T>` is not thread safe, so you'll need synchronization (or a thread safe collection, such as `ConcurrentBag<T>`).

Note that this won't terminate running threads.  If you want to stop an operation that's running, you should use [.NET's cooperative cancellation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364.aspx) and set a `CancellationTokenSource` to it's canceled state, at which point your thread can exit itself gracefully.

Comment: Following your good advice, I've replaced concurrently accessed Lists with ConcurrentBags. So, apart from the question at hand, I should no more user Monitor.TryEnter / Monitor.Exit when accessing them right? As of now I'm reading the part about cooperative cancellation and then try to implement what you said. I'll let you know about the results.

Comment: @CarloArnaboldi Yes - you can add/remove items from `ConcurrentBag<T>` without lock or monitor.enter...

Comment: Just a quick note to let you know that I managed to close other threads just by checking TcpClient.Connected value. Of course you couldn't suggest that since I didn't expose any detail of my program. Thanks anyway for the useful advice, I'll keep that in mind for future reference.